# Is Apple slowing down older iPads too?

Tags: ios, ipad

Is Apple slowing down older iPads too?

Apple said it's slowing down older iPhones which you can disable under battery health, but I think Apple is slowing down iPads too. I watched this  https://youtu.be/Mpq6Ib1IVdA?t=7m49s YouTube video today in which the reviewer said that Apple has slowed down his 2 years old iPad Pro 12.9 inch.

If this is true then how can I find out if Apple has slowed my iPad pro too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apples Information the iPads should not be affected.

[Apple Support Document:](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208387)

> With a low battery state of charge, a higher chemical age, or colder
>   temperatures, users are more likely to experience unexpected
>   shutdowns. In extreme cases, shutdowns can occur more frequently,
>   thereby rendering the device unreliable or unusable. iOS 10.2.1
>   (Released January 2017) includes updates for previous models of iPhone
>   to prevent them from unexpectedly shutting down. This includes a
>   feature for **iPhone 6, iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 6s, iPhone 6s Plus, and
>   iPhone SE** to dynamically manage the instantaneous performance peaks,
>   only when needed, to prevent the device from unexpectedly shutting
>   down. This capability was also extended to iPhone 7 and iPhone 7 Plus
>   with iOS 11.2, and we will continue improving our power management
>   feature in the future. This feature's only intent is to prevent
>   unexpected shutdowns so that the iPhone can still be used.

So the feature (or issue as some see it) is not present on the iPad.
The iPad under the circumstances that the battery can't deliver the necessary power would shut down and not try to throttle performance.

Comment: If this is true then what's the reason behind laggy touch response and performance issue in the iPad mentioned in the review

Comment: @Sayan Could be any number of reasons. We can hardly diagnose the device based on that information. Could be a software issue or even a (although unlikely) hardware issue. A lot of comments on the video state no experience like that, furthermore a lot of people report resetting their device solved similar issues.

Comment: a complete factory reset